# Table border collapse not working with inline-block?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This example displays two tables in two different ways.  In the first case, one table is above the other.  In the second, they are side by side.  The only differences between the two cases are that one uses `display: inline-block`; also, in the first case, the tables are separated by `<DIV>` with a `padding-bottom`, and in the second they are separated by a `<SPAN>` with a `padding-right`.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Title</TITLE>
   <STYLE type="text/css">
   table { border-collapse: collapse; border-style: solid; border-width: thin }
   col { border-style: dotted; border-width: thin } 
   td { padding-left: 0.05in; padding-right: 0.05in }
   </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
   <TABLE>
   <COL><COL><COL><COL><COL><COL>
   <TR><TD>x<TD>x<TD>x<TD>x<TD>x<TD>x</TABLE>
   <DIV style="padding-bottom: 1em"></DIV>
   <TABLE>
   <COL><COL><COL><COL><COL><COL>
   <TR><TD>y<TD>y<TD>y<TD>y<TD>y<TD>y</TABLE>

   <DIV style="padding-bottom: 3em"></DIV>

   <TABLE style="display: inline-block">
   <COL><COL><COL><COL><COL><COL>
   <TR><TD>x<TD>x<TD>x<TD>x<TD>x<TD>x</TABLE>
   <SPAN style="padding-right: 3em"></SPAN>
   <TABLE style="display: inline-block">
   <COL><COL><COL><COL><COL><COL>
   <TR><TD>y<TD>y<TD>y<TD>y<TD>y<TD>y</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

17.6.2.1 of the [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html) spec says about resolving border conflicts in the collapsing border model:

> If none of the styles are 'hidden' and at least one of them is not 'none', then narrow borders are discarded in favor of wider ones. If several have the same 'border-width' then styles are preferred in this order: 'double', 'solid', 'dashed', 'dotted', 'ridge', 'outset', 'groove', and the lowest: 'inset'.

This seems to be working in the first case, where the solid border wins over the dotted one, around the edge of the table.  But in the second case, it looks like *both* borders are showing up, perhaps one pixel apart.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm observing this behavior both in Chrome 37.0 and IE11.

Browser bug, or CSS feature?  Is there a way to get it to work right in the `inline-block` case?

Note: Eliminating all the white space between HTML tags didn't help.

Comment: Please let me know if this is a duplicate.  I ran into network problems when I first tried to ask this.

Comment: I just tested this in Chrome 37.0 and IE 11 and it works just like expected. (not like your screenshot)

Comment: @MårtenWikström On what system?  I'm on a Windows 8 laptop.  Bizarre that it would make a difference, but you never know.  The exact Chrome version is 37.0.2062.120.

Comment: Try to recreate the issue in jsFiddle - you will probably find the problem while recreating it.

Comment: @ajb I'm on Windows 8 too and use the exact same version of Chrome.

Comment: @ajb But it only works for me when I pasted your HTML into a local file. Not when running the FIDDLE from @Danield with `inline-block` set. `inline-table` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what it's worth, to get this to work right use `inline-table` instead of `inline-block`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7a964ahj/1/)**

Also, I don't think you should ever set a table element with anything but

`display:table` , `display:inline-table` ( or `display:none` - if necessary)

-- otherwise things are bound to mess up because you're telling the table not to behave like a table anymore.

Comment: @misterManSam are you sure this is related to collapsing margins?

Comment: Strange. When I pasted OP's HTML into a local file it showed up just like expected (even with `inline-block`). But the fiddle in this answer do not work when I change it to `inline-block`. +1 for `inline-table`

Comment: @misterManSam - This question has nothing to do with collapsing margins. It is about collapsing borders and the fact that `border-collapse` does not apply if the table element ceases to be a CSS table.

Comment: Thanks!  I see `inline-table` in the CSS spec now but I missed it earlier.  Life is perfect now.  (Well, this tiny part of life, anyway...)